# Why my edit was reverted by a moderator?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I have edited this post https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5902551/revisions to add yet another relevant item to the list of `3D Android Game Engines`. However, moderator declined my edit.

Why? I suggested the relevant open source product.

Comment: It's a shopping question from a year and half ago that was closed (correctly) and shouldn't be on the site in the first place. I suggest you focus on more constructive edits to questions that are more useful in general.

Comment: You already have [an answer of your own](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206089/game-engine-for-android/8402207#8402207) describing and linking to your product. It wasn't *at all* necessary to add another link to the top-voted answer for the sake of it.

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand: It was closed exactly after i posted an answer there. The motivation was: developers should disclose their involvement in the product they recommend. The post was edited so the SO rules are respected.

Comment: @BoltClock's a Unicorn: indeed, either one is sufficient.

Comment: That often happens when an old, was-once-on-topic-but-is-no-longer-so question gets noticed by a moderator. It had nothing to do with your edit specifically but your edit made it more visible.

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand: ok, i see. Was too much mess with it: the answer was deleted, then the question was edited, then reverted, then the answer was undeleted.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Your answer includes a disclosure that you're one of the developers of the engine you're promoting.  The top answer that you edited did not include that disclosure.  Please don't insert your links into other people's answers.

Comment: Isn't this against SO rules? It is always better to edit the old answer slightly (if it is possible) than to add new one, isn't it?

Comment: @SergeyK. To insert a link to your own project?  No.  That's borderline spammy.

Comment: ok, but where is the boundary when it is still bearable?

Comment: @SergeyK. If you need to make a minor and obvious correction to someone else's answer, go ahead and edit it.  Adding new information of any kind is generally frowned upon, since it's not what the original author of the answer intended.  Putting your own links into someone else's answer is way beyond that line.  It makes it look like someone else is endorsing your project, which they aren't.

Comment: "It makes it look like someone else is endorsing your project". Ok, now i've got the exact point of it. It is reasonable and exhaustive explanation.